Possible to dot your Is with hearts?
I was wondering if it is possible to replace just the mathmode i from the default latex font with nearly the same letter, but where the dot on the i is a small heart. For example:

Thank you!

Is Valentine's day approaching again? Time flies ...

@gernot Check out the Visigothic O on p. 29 of https://www.typofonts.com/LATIN_PALEOGRAPHY.pdf

@gernot But with os rather than is?

@cfr Yes, sure. Different time, different culture, different letter. 500 years from now it will be the letter M, as most scientists agree.

Why not also j?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\iheart}{}{\mathord{\mathpalette\iheart@{\imath{7}{1}}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\jheart}{}{\mathord{\mathpalette\iheart@{\jmath{12}{2}}}}
\newcommand{\iheart@}[2]{\iheart@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\iheart@@}[4]{%
  \vbox{\m@th\offinterlineskip
    \sbox\z@{$\mkern1mu$}%
    \ialign{##\cr\hidewidth\smallheart@{#1}{#3}\hidewidth\cr\noalign{\kern\wd\z@}\cr$#1#2$\cr}%
  }%
  \mkern#4mu
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \smallheart@ #1 #2
 {
  \draw_begin:
  \draw_transform_matrix_absolute:nnnn { 0.4 } { 0 } { 0.2 } { 0.3 }
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0cm, 0cm }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \boldmath$#1\mkern#2mu\heartsuit$ }
  \draw_box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
  \draw_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$2\pi\iheart_{\jheart}+\jheart$

\end{document}


How do the macros work? First off, some mathpalette trickery to have four arguments:

the current math style, as usual
the letter to be typeset, so either \imath and \jmath
the (math) kern in front of the heart
the math kern after the combination, to compense for the protrusion of the heart which is not taken into account because of \hidewidth

I make a \vbox with \ialign inside it that oversets the heart to the letter.
Finally, the heart is a bold \heartsuit in the suitable math style subject to an affine transformation that applies reduction and shearing.
Maybe some more experiments are needed for the various parameters.

Thanks! I was going to ask for j as well, but I wasn't sure if that would be too much of a hassle! You're a tex wizard!


\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$2\pi{\mathop{{}\imath}\limits^{\scriptscriptstyle\heartsuit}}$
\end{document}



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\newcommand\iheart[1][\imath]{%
#1\kern-.2em\rlap{%
\raisebox{1.2ex}[0pt][0pt]{%
\rotatebox{-15}{%
\resizebox{.5ex}{.5ex}{\ensuremath{\heartsuit}}}}}\kern.2em} 
\begin{document}
\Huge  \[ 2\pi ii\iheart ii  =  2\pi\iheart[\jmath] \]
\end{document}


I get quite a lot of errors with this code. You are missing the $ in the argument of \resizebox.

@campa. Oh, sorry, yes, it fail miserably with pdlatex and xelatex for this reason, but it works as is with lualatex (bug or feature? haha).

Added \ensuremath for engine compatibility

Oh, didn't think of trying with luatex. Interesting...
